# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token. Quoting issues?

Tags: javascript

This is code that causes error. (The error message just refers to its first line.) It doesn't say which token is invalid or unexpected.

```
    tpl: function(data){return '<form class="new_relation" id="new_relation" action="/relations/add_dependency" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input value="3101" type="hidden" name="relation[to_id]" id="relation_to_id" />
  <input value="1" type="hidden" name="relation[graph]" id="relation_graph" />
  <select class="select-article" name="relation[from_id]" id="relation_from_id"></select>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add a dependency of this article." data-disable-with="Add a dependency of this article." />
</form>';}
```

Comment: is tpl a property of an object? Can you show what is around this line.

Comment: What was the operation that threw the error? What were you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape every new line or use backticks instead.

```
tpl: function(data){  
      return `<form class="new_relation" id="new_relation" action="/relations/add_dependency" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
      <input value="3101" type="hidden" name="relation[to_id]" id="relation_to_id" />
      <input value="1" type="hidden" name="relation[graph]" id="relation_graph" />
      <select class="select-article" name="relation[from_id]" id="relation_from_id"></select>
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add a dependency of this article." data-disable-with="Add a dependency of this article." />
    </form>`;
}
```